# Deus, Luís de Camões, o livro "os lusíadas" e as reformas ortográficas da língua portuguesa

Tags: ortografia, mudanças-históricas

Por que os nomes próprios foram alterados ao passar do tempo? O que Lvis de Camoens, tem com a reforma ortográfica da língua portuguesa? Pois, que, agora, é lembrado por um nome que não lhe pertencia, e este: Luis de Camões. E até Deos, está a ser chamado: Deus. Estou certo, ou há alguma incoerência neste meu pensamento? Se sim, e tiverdes entendimento para corrigir-me, por favor, corrijam-me.
No livro "os lusíadas", de Luis de Camões (ou Lvis de Camoens, se preferirdes), se nele havia(m) lucidez(es), perdeu sentido(s) lúcido(s), (se lido em língua portuguesa atual). Poucas pessoas, conseguem lê-lo, em suas palavras originais, em dias atuais, compreendendo-o.
Quanto aos livros de Deus (Deos), escritos em várias línguas, "a Torá, o Evangelho e o Alcorão", segundo os dicionários de língua portuguesa, não podem ser traduzidos perfeitamente, para a língua portuguesa. Pois, que, muitas das palavras da língua portuguesa, que 'tradutores', usaram para 'traduzi-los', não correspondem aos significados perfeitos, que encontramos para as palavras originais, em dicionários, de línguas, nas quais os livros de Deus foram escritos originalmente. Vejo como: Se não há palavras, para se fazer tradução, em quaisquer outras palavras usadas, como 'tradução', haverá alterações de sentidos. Daí, surgiram várias 'traduções diferentes', com significados diferentes. Como poderemos nós, aprender outros idiomas, tentando traduzir suas palavras, usando palavras que tem significados diferentes? Penso que, por estes motivos, causamos muitos desentendimentos, e conflictos em conversas nas quais não se tem intenção de ferir a outrem. Fico a pensar: "Quando entenderemos o que querem dizer-nos? Se não estudarmos os sentidos originais das palavras, não entenderemos o que os estrangeiros querem dizer-nos, e nem mesmo eles, se não souberem o real significado do que estamos a dizer, não entenderão nossas pretensões".

Comment: Podemos ir mais longe... Como sabemos que as outras pessoas entendem o que dizemos da mesma forma que nós? Em todo o caso, a pergunta parece-me mais do domínio da filosofia da linguagem, e não tem que ver especificamente com o português.

Comment: Não sei porque dizes isso. A confusão que criamos é geral, parecendo possivelmente, acontecida entre todos os idiomas que já falamos. Na língua portuguesa, não há tradução perfeita para todas as palavras que se entendem em outras línguas. Sendo assim, não podemos entender perfeitamente o que se diz em outras línguas, com a excepção de podermos estudá-las em seus sentidos originais, como se faz com um nativo de um país, desde bebé,  que aprende seu idioma local, a partir do modo como está em seus dicionários, e não da maneira que 'como costumamos dizer: Traduzimos' (erradamente).

Comment: O que pensais sobre a alteração no nome de Luis de Camões? Talvez,  futuramente, nossos nomes também não sejam reconhecidos, pela língua portuguesa.

Comment: É um mau exemplo, nesse caso foi a ortografia que foi alterada, a qual é meramente convencional. Terias melhor argumento com _Cleopátra_, por exemplo (do latim _Cleopatra_). Alguns nomes de figuras históricas são traduzidos ou adaptados, outros não... Em todo o caso, a tua pergunta não tem a forma requerida para este _site_. Tocas demasiados temas (muitos dos quais do domínio da filosofia, e mais apropriados para [este site](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)) e de forma demasiado aberta. Tenta colocar perguntas específicas e mais objetivas do que _o que pensas de X?_.

Comment: A pergunta objetiva poderia ter sido feita se eliminasses a partir do final da frase onde referes _Deos_.

Comment: Qual é **a** pergunta, concretamente? Fico confuso com tanto palavreado. Não se pode clarificar esta pergunta?